# MD5 Hash using ts-md5 is different from S3 ETag

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, ts-md5

I need to check the integrity of a file before and after upload of a file to/from S3 bucket. So for this I am using ts-md5 package in angular to upload. The hash generated by ts-md5 is matching with ETag in S3 bucket file when I upload image file or files less than 2 mb. but when I upload files like 10 mb 20 mb files in this case the hash generated by ts-md5 is not matching with ETag in S3 bucket file. Please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: hey, welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: krunal-shah, Please let me know what you did not get

Comment: I have check the below link: https://www.savjee.be/2015/10/Verifying-Amazon-S3-multi-part-uploads-with-ETag-hash/           It says: "To calculate the first part you have to make a list of md5 hashes of all your parts, convert it into binary format and take the md5 hash of it. Afterwards you append a dash and add the number of parts you've split your file in. ", please let me know what changes need to do using ts-md5 package.

Comment: what is the part size for splitting chunks

Comment: I have further did analysis to find where the mismatch is. md5 and ETag same for each chunk but after merging not same, please refer this link for code. Anyone can please help me on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633483/calculate-s3-etag-locally-using-spark-md5

Answer (score 0):

For now, I solved it my self by single chunk, only one hash where S3 ETag and md5 hash generated locally are both same