# Calculate S3 ETag locally using spark md5

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, md5, angular8

I have uploaded a file 14MB to S3 in chunks (5MB) each and also using spark-md5 calculated the hash of each chunk. The individual hash of each chunk (generated by spark-md5) is matching with ETag of each chunk uploaded to S3.

But the ETag hash generated by doing full upload to S3 is not matching with locally calculated hash generated by spark-md5. Below are the steps for local hash:

1. Generate hash (generated by spark-md5) of each chunk
2. Join the hash of each chunk
3. Convert to hex
4. Calculated hash

Below is the code, please check if there is any mistake.
Approach 1:

```
        var mergeChunk = self.chunkArray.join('');
        console.log("mergeChunk: " + mergeChunk);

        var hexString = toHexString(mergeChunk);
        console.log("toHexString: " + hexString);

        var cspark1 = SparkMD5.hash(hexString);
        console.log("SparkMD5 final hash: " + cspark1);
```

Approach 2:

```
       var mergeChunk = self.chunkArray.join('');
       console.log("mergeChunk: " + mergeChunk);
       var cspark2 = SparkMD5.hash(mergeChunk);
       console.log("SparkMD5 final hash: " + cspark2);
```

Please provide correct logic for calculating ETag.

Answer (score 0):

etags are meant to be opaque; AWS don't make any guarantees as to what to the tag of a multipart upload is.

I think it is just the cat of the blocks (in the order listed in the final POST), but you cannot rely on that.